# Application tried to present modally an active controller using storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I am developing first tutorial using story board my requirement is i have two textfields and one button.  When i click on button, If textfields are not empty i want to navigate V1Controller to V2Controller. For that i am  i am dragging from V1Controller to V2Controller and giving style "Model" and my identifier is "DestinationView" in Storyboard .
Here i am writing code in  V1Controller  on button click

```
if(!userField.text.length==0 && !passwordField.text.length==0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"DestinationView" sender: self];
    }


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DestinationView"])
    {
        SecondViewController *sVC =segue.destinationViewController;
        [self presentViewController:sVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

When I Click on button the app is crashing and giving the following exemption:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT invoke `presentViewController` inside `prepareForSegue` in your case. This what the framework does for u.

The `prepareForSegue` should be used if u want to load the `destinationViewController` with some data, for example.

Comment: Thanks bro for your quick response i just delete the following code  SecondViewController *sVC =segue.destinationViewController;
        [self presentViewController:sVC animated:YES completion:NO];
Now working fine

Comment: i have one more issue. I am adding navigationController to V1Controller like Editor----> EmbededIn--->NavigationController. How to use same navigationController to V2Controller

Comment: I can tell u what to do, but the best for u is to read short tutorial like this:http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/ and u have many more. good luck!